# Map API Key doesn't works in Android app

Tags: java, android, google-maps

i've been working for a while in an Android app that uses a lot of the Maps API. And the thing is it works in the emulator with my debug key, but i see only a grid when i put "true" key, i tried with three already that i know they worked, so why could it be? I have internet permission (in the right place, befoce ) and i just can't find why this thing only works with the debug key.

Comment: Don't you need to sign and deploy your app to be able to use the "true" (i.e. not the debug) key? See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html and here: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html